# On Google Analytics, is it possible to trace the behavior path of a conversion back to the landing page?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

On Google Analytics, I am looking to see the exact path that a user took up until the point that a goal conversion was made. Currently, I can see the last three steps via Reverse Goal Path, but I would like to see the steps before that, all the way back to the landing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the full path of your goals in the User Flow report (however it's in reverse - from the landing page to the conversion). Use the "Converters" segment to refine your report.

Comment: Just hit upon this valuable answer today.  For me, filtering to *Converters* for some reason returned no data (an error actually), but *Sessions with Conversions* worked great.